# Image cropper modal doesn't work by multiple usage

Tags: php, laravel

image cropper does not work when I want to crop multiple images. The function works when I test the code separately, but when I put it in an if else statement the popup to crop the image does not pop up. can someone help me with that?

```
 @if($location_type === 'CULTURE')
                        @if ($location->culture_file)
                            <p>Actual:</p>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset($location->culture_file)}}"/>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <button type="button" onclick="$('#modalInputFile-lesson-{{$location->type}}').modal('show');" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update new image</button>
                            @component('components.edit_image', [
                                           'url' => "/admin/location/$location->id/culture_image",
                                           'isSquare' => false,
                                           'random' => "lesson-$location->type"
                                          ]
                                      )
                            @endcomponent
                      @elseif($location_type === 'HISTORY')
                        @if ($location->history_file)
                            <p>Actual:</p>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                 <img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset($location->history_file)}}"/>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <button type="button" onclick="$('#modalInputFile-lesson-{{$location->type}}').modal('show');" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update new image</button>
                            @component('components.edit_image', [
                                           'url' => "/admin/location/$location->id/history_image",
                                           'isSquare' => false,
                                           'random' => "lesson-$location->type"
                                          ]
                                      )
                            @endcomponent
                        @endif
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in js console?

Comment: no nothing, the model works when i use 1 location_type. But when i want to use 2 location_types on one page it doesn't work by the second one.

Comment: try to look into html source and compare the actual html output for case where it works and where it doesn't work. Look for repeated tag IDs ect...